# load weights require h5py

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to run a keras model,trying to use pre-trained VGGnet-
When i run this Command
`base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))`

I get this error:

```
  ``------------------------------------------------------------------
---------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-79-9b18deb3bc0f> in <module>()
  1 
----> 2 base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py in 
VGG16(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, 
classes)
167                                     WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
168                                     cache_subdir='models')
--> 169         model.load_weights(weights_path)
170         if K.backend() == 'theano':
171             layer_utils.convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in 
load_weights(self, filepath, by_name)
   2563         """
   2564         if h5py is None:
-> 2565             raise ImportError('`load_weights` requires h5py.')
   2566         f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
   2567         if 'layer_names' not in f.attrs and 'model_weights' in f:

ImportError: `load_weights` requires h5py.``
```

I went through some github issues page where a relevant question was asked,but no solutions were given.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install h5py:

```
pip install h5py
```

Or if using conda:

```
conda install h5py
```

Comment: @Ryan check your python path: `echo $PYTHONPATH`. It can prevent it to be loaded. After, you use conda? If so, check that you are in the right environment.

Comment: how do i check my python path?

Comment: @Ryan as I said in the terminal do: `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Ryan ok so if using conda it means that it will only use the packages loaded with the current env. Is it working if you just import h5py?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151655/discussion-between-ryan-and-y0da).

Answer (score 7):

technically you need dependencies, such as:

```
pip install cython
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
pip install h5py
```

And restart your jupyter notebok.

Comment: This is the one! `sudo apt-get install libhdf5` fixed it for me :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

in the case that "pip install h5py" does not work, and you see something like: "... already satisfied". in python 3 use "pip3 install h5py"/ this will work.

Answer (score 1):

the below steps solved my issue

```
conda uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```

Answer (score 0):

the below steps solve this error for me :

```
conda uninstall h5py
pip uninstall h5py
```

then install with conda:

```
conda  install -c anaconda  h5py
```